# canvas drawing Paint loop code

Tags: java, android

I'm drawing circles to the canvas every time I touch the screen.  I add them to an arraylist of paths in the onTouch method. In my onDraw method, I loop through the array, drawing them.

When I try to change the paint of one of the circles, it changes them all.  I don't want this, just want it to apply to one specific circle.  How can I do that?

Code:

```
//on touch method
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    mode = Drag;
    x =(int) event.getX();
    y =(int) event.getY();
    path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 8, Path.Direction.CCW);
    mpaint.setARGB(255, mcolor[0],100, mcolor[2]);
    circle.add(path);
    invalidate();

//on draw method
for (Path c : circle) {
    canvas.drawPath(c, mpaint);
}
```

Comment: //on touch method                                                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                                           mode = Drag;                                                         x =(int) event.getX();
   y =(int) event.getY();
     
           path = new   Path();
   path.addCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 8,Path.Direction.CCW);
   mpaint.setARGB(255, mcolor[0],100, mcolor[2]);

     circle.add(path);
  invalidate();

Comment: //on draw method for(Path c : circle)
 {
   canvas.drawPath(c, mpaint);
    
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Store a separate Paint object along with each circle
2. Query the Paint for the current values of whatever you are changing, and then restore them after drawing the circle.